# Doing an operation to a class's member

Tags: c++, class

I am working on a project for my School's Science Fair that involves C++. I am making a small simulation under the name of NANORGs, but this information isn't really that necessary.

I have several files, including main.cpp and bots.h.

I am having an issue with my moveBot() function. I am totally stumped on how I would add or subtract a value from a member; whatever I try, it just sets it to that number.

Example.) bots[botID].y_cord = bots[botID].y_cord - 1;     would make y_cord equal to -1.

bot.h:

```
class Bot
{
        public:
                int id;
                int x_cord;
                int y_cord;
                int energy;
                int mutationLevel;
                int magical; //Used for debugging
};
```

main.cpp (moveBot is on the bottom):

```
// NANORG SIMULATION
// CREATED BY *INSERT NAME HERE* FOR THE SCIENCE FAIR (2013)
// CODED IN C++

// MADE TO RUN ON LINUX

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "bot.h"

using namespace std;

int map [39][69]; //2D array  x first, then y
int mapBot [39][69]; //If bot is there, 1. If not, 0   This array keeps track if there is a bot in a location
signed int currentTick = 0; //Signed just in case something goes wrong and goes into the -s
int maxTick = 1000000; //Should always stay at 1mil
//signed int totalEnergy = 0;  //For some reason, when I add this here, everything breaks.

Bot bots[50];

void setupMap();
void tick();
void updateTickOutput();
void outputMapValue(int x, int y);
void assignBotID();
void setupBot();
void moveBot(int botID);
void mutateBot(int botID, int level, int sT);
void ckLoc(int botIdent);
void reassignLoc(int botID);

int main() {
    cout << "     ----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "     NANORG Simulation V1.3.1" << endl;
    cout << "Created in C++ by *Insert name here*" << endl;
    cout << "     ----------------------" << endl << endl;
        srand (time(NULL));
    setupMap();
    assignBotID();
    setupBot();
    tick();
//  mutateBot(5, 2); //Just to test
    cout << endl << "X before: " << bots[5].x_cord << " Y before: " << bots[5].y_cord << endl;
    moveBot(5);
        cout << "X after: " << bots[5].x_cord << " Y after: " << bots[5].y_cord << endl;
    return 0;
}

void setupMap(){
//  srand (time(NULL)); //Not a good idea to put it here
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 70; j++){ // We add one extra (70) so it fills the entire array. Same for above
            map[i][j] = rand() % 2 + 1; // 1==normal 2==toxic
        }
    }
//  outputMapValue(5,4); //Debugging purposes
//  outputMapValue(7,9);
    cout << "Map setup - \033[0;32mSuccessful" << "\033[0m" << endl;
}

void outputMapValue(int x, int y){
    cout << "The chunk value at (" << x+1 << ", " << y+1 << ") is: ";
    cout << map[x][y]; //Outputting the value of (x,y)
    if(map[x][y]==1){ //If (x,y) is == 1, the chunk is fine to eat
        cout << "  |  Chunk is not toxic." << endl;
    }
    if(map[x][y]==2){
        cout << "  |  Chunk is toxic." << endl;
    }
}

void updateTickOutput() {
        //cout << "Map Size (x,y): " << " " <<  mapsizeX << "," << mapsizeY << endl;      This function used to just refresh everything, including map size, which really isn't needed.
        cout << "Current Tick: " << currentTick << " " << "Max Tick: " << maxTick << endl; //Just outputting currentTick and maxTick
}

void tick() {
        while(true){
                if(currentTick < maxTick){
                        currentTick = currentTick + 1;
            if(currentTick >= 900000){ //If currentTick is over 900,000: we will begin to output individual ticks. Anything less and we get a seg fault.
        //      updateTickOutput(); //See above
            }
//          cout << "tick!";       This was for debugging, before I made the updateTickOutput() function to make sure that the program actually ticked.
                }
                else if((currentTick = maxTick)){
                        cout << endl << "Done!" << endl; //Report that we are finished with the simulation.
//          assignBotID(); //Make sure every bot has the proper ID. Moved to main()
                        break; //Kill the loop
                }
//                updateTickOutput(); //No real need for this, anymore.
        }
}

void setupBot(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int botNumber=0;botNumber <= 50; botNumber++){
//          cout << "debug (botNumber): " << botNumber << endl;  //Debug feature
            bots[botNumber].x_cord = rand() % 39 + 1;
//          cout << "debug (bot x cord): " << bots[botNumber].x_cord << endl;  //Debug feature
            int bufferX = bots[botNumber].x_cord;
            bots[botNumber].y_cord = rand() % 69 + 1;
//          cout << "debug (bot y cord): " << bots[botNumber].y_cord << endl;  //Debug feature
            int bufferY = bots[botNumber].y_cord;
            if(mapBot[bufferX][bufferY] == 1){
                cout << endl <<"A bot already is here!" << endl;
                reassignLoc(botNumber);
            }
            else{
                mapBot[bufferX][bufferY] = 1; //Take the bot's cords and make sure everyone knows that a bot is there.
//              cout<< "debug (map location):"<<mapBot[bufferX][bufferY] << endl ;   Just a nice debug feature
            }
        //  if(botNumber==5){
        //      cout << "bot 5 assigned";    //I broke this entire function a while back and I used this to test if I was assigning bots correctly.
        //  }
    }

/*  cout << endl << "X: " << bots[5].x_cord+1 << endl;   //Just some debugging stuff below
    cout << "Y: " << bots[5].y_cord+1 << endl;
   //   cout << "The value at " << mapBot[bots[5].x_cord]<<","<< mapBot[bots[5].y_cord]<<" is: "  << mapBot[bots[5].x_cord][bots[5].y_cord];   //This is a very messed up debug feature, but it still works.

        cout << endl << "X: " << bots[6].x_cord+1 << endl;
        cout << "Y: " << bots[6].y_cord+1 << endl;
    cout << mapBot[6][6];
*/
    cout << "Bot setup - \033[0;32mSuccessful" << "\033[0m" << endl;
}

void assignBotID(){
    int botNumber = 0;
    string botName = "Bot";
    string finalName;

    string buffer;

    while(botNumber <50){
        if(botNumber < 50){
            botNumber = botNumber + 1;
            buffer = to_string(botNumber);
            finalName = botName + buffer;
            //finalName.id = botNumber;  A very very broken line.
            bots[botNumber].id = botNumber;
//          cout << finalName << ":"<< bots[botNumber].id << endl;  A super awesome debugging output to make sure the bot's id is correct
        }
        else if((botNumber = 51)){ //Redundancy :)
            break;
        }
    }
}

void mutateBot(int botID, int level, int sT){
    if(sT=2){
        bots[botID].mutationLevel = bots[botID].mutationLevel + level;
    }
    else if(sT=1){
        bots[botID].mutationLevel = bots[botID].mutationLevel - level;
    }
//  cout << botID << ":" << bots[botID].mutationLevel << endl; //Just a quick debugging feature to make sure it worked
}

void ckLoc(int botIdent){
    int bufferX;
    int bufferY;
    bufferX = bots[botIdent].x_cord;  //Just set the buffers. Uses a bit more memory, but that is okay.
    bufferY = bots[botIdent].y_cord;
//  cout << bufferX << endl << bufferY;
    if(mapBot[bufferX][bufferY] ==1){
        cout << "Bot lives here!";
        reassignLoc(botIdent);
    }
}

void reassignLoc(int botID){
    bots[botID].x_cord = rand() % 39 + 1;
    bots[botID].y_cord = rand() % 69 + 1;
    ckLoc(botID);
}

void moveBot(int botID){
    int direction = 0;
    direction = rand() % 4 + 1;
    if(direction == 1){ //NORTH
        if(bots[botID].y_cord=0){
            //cout << "error moving bot - N ";
            moveBot(botID);
        }
        else{
            //cout << "BufferY: " << bufferY;
            bots[botID].y_cord - 1;
        }
    }
    else if(direction == 2){ //EAST
        if(bots[botID].x_cord  = 39){
            //cout << "error moving bot - E";
            moveBot(botID);
        }
        else{
            bots[botID].x_cord + 1;
        }
    }
        else if(direction == 3){ //SOUTH
                if(bots[botID].y_cord  = 69){
                        //cout << "error moving bot - S ";
                        moveBot(botID);
                }
                else{
                        bots[botID].y_cord + 1;
                }
        }
        else if(direction == 4){ //WEST
                if(bots[botID].x_cord  = 0){
                        //cout << "error moving bot - W";
                        moveBot(botID);
                }
                else{
                        bots[botID].x_cord = bots[botID].x_cord - 1;
                }
        }
//  cout << endl << "Direction: " << direction << endl; //Debug
}
```

Also, I am aware of the while loops. I have to clean everything up before I hand the project in.

Comment: simonc's answer is correct but the code in your example before your code snippet 
`bots[botID].y_cord = bots[botID].y_cord - 1;` is also technically correct. Perhaps what you were seeing is because y_cord was actually 0 so subtracting 1 made the value -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All lines of the form

```
if(bots[botID].y_cord=0)
```

are assigning to `bots[botID].y_cord`.  You need to use `==` to test for equality

```
if(bots[botID].y_cord==0)
//                    ^
```

Also, lines of the form

```
bots[botID].x_cord + 1;
```

should be

```
bots[botID].x_cord += 1;
```

if you want to affect the value of `bots[botID].x_cord`

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I did that. This is the second time I have messed up with equal signs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `switch` statement instead of the `if-else-if` ladder.

```
switch (direction)
{
  case 1:
  // do stuff
    break;
  case 2:
  // do stuff
    break;
  // etc.
}
```

For your program, it will look more readable and have fewer chances for errors.